# Export users from AD with certain fields

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have having some difficulty regarding getting certain information in a csv formatted a certain way.

I need the following fields in this order:

```
Email   First Name  Last Name   Group   Location    
Department  Manager First Name  Manager Last Name   
Manager Email   Employee Number Job Title   Business Unit   Cost Center
```

The majority of these I can easily do but I'm not sure how to handle the manager info. because to pull the manager it simply pulls the DN. Can anyone help me one this?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * 
    | Select-Object mail, GivenName, SN, department, 
    | export-csv -path c:\temp\userexport.csv`
```

Comment: Don't query all properties just to select a few. If the manager field still suffices with what you're looking for, you can split (*or just regex*) to get just their name using a calculated property. Alternatively, you can use that same field to query for the managers display name using another calculated field and just using another `Get-ADUser` call providing the dn that's returned.

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties  mail, GivenName, SN, department, Manager | Select-Object -Property mail, GivenName, SN, department, @{n='Manager';E={(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager -Property DisplayName).DisplayName}}`

Answer (score 0):

Get-ADUser already by default returns these properties:
`DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName`

For the others you need to use the `-Properties` parameter.

Although not familiar with the LDAP names for properties `Group`, `Business Unit` or `Cost Center`, I think they may be named `defaultGroup`, `ou` and `businessCategory` respectively.
Feel free to corrent me on that.

```
$userProps = 'EmailAddress','defaultGroup','Office','Department','Manager','EmployeeNumber','Title','ou','businessCategory'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $userProps | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        # this may fail if the user has its 'Manager' property not set. In that case we enter the catch block
        $mgr = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager -Properties EmailAddress -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch { <# do nothing here, we'll test if there is a manager later #> }
    # output an object with the desired properties
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Email'              = $_.EmailAddress
        'First Name'         = $_.GivenName
        'Last Name'          = $_.Surname
        'Group'              = $_.defaultGroup
        'Location'           = $_.Office
        'Department'         = $_.Department
        'Manager First Name' = if ($mgr) { $mgr.GivenName } else { 'Not available' }
        'Manager Last Name'  = if ($mgr) { $mgr.Surname } else { 'Not available' }
        'Manager Email'      = if ($mgr) { $mgr.EmailAddress } else { 'Not available' }
        'Employee Number'    = $_.EmployeeNumber
        'Job Title'          = $_.Title
        'Business Unit'      = $_.ou
        'Cost Center'        = $_.businessCategory
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\userexport.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I there a way to run this against all the AD users instead of having to pick a specific user?

Comment: @1nVasiv3 I don't know what you mean... The code is already running against all users, not just one in particular

Comment: When I ran this command, this is what was returned.

et-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try 
running the command again.
At line:3 char:33
+     $mgr = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager -Properties EmailAddress
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException

Comment: @1nVasiv3 Aha, so not all your users have their Manager attribute filled in. Please see my edit to catch that when it happens.